# In what sense are independent random vectors "independent"?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Let's say we have independent random vectors $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}$, where $\boldsymbol{X}=(X_{1},...,X_{p})$ and $\boldsymbol{Y}=(Y_{1},...,Y_{q})$. What is it that makes them independent? Are the $X_i$ independent of the $X_j$ ($i \neq j$)? Are the $X_i$ independent of the $Y_j$? Is it that $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=0, \forall i\neq j$, or $\text{Cov}(X_i,Y_j)=0$? Are these vectors independent in some other sense?

Comment: In fact, the independence is the matter of $\sigma-$fields and not just random variables. And the notion is the same for one-dimensional/$n$-dimensional or even random variables with  values in abstract space. Let's say we have $X:\Omega \to E_1$ and $Y:\Omega \to E_2$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal F),(E_1,\mathcal E_1),(E_2,\mathcal E_2)$ are measurable spaces. Then $\sigma(X),\sigma(Y)$ are independent ( $X,Y$ are independent) iff $\mathbb P(X \in A, Y \in B) =\mathbb P(X \in A)\mathbb P(Y \in B)$ for any $A \in \mathcal E_1,B \in \mathcal E_2$.

Comment: Now for your question, independence of vectors $X=(X_1,...,X_p)$ and $Y=(Y_1,...,Y_q)$ implies independence of $X_i,Y_j$ for any $i,j$ (so $Cov(X_i,Y_j)=0$, too), but nothing more. You can't say $X_i,X_j$ are independent or even $Cov(X_i,X_j)=0$. Counterexample is simple. Take any non-degenerate independent random variables $X_1,Y_1$ and put $X=(X_1,X_1)$ and $Y=(Y_1,Y_1)$. Then $X,Y$ are independent, however $X_1,X_1$ aren't independent (since non-degenerate)

Comment: See also this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442799/532409

Comment: @mrcntn yes, this helps, thank you

Comment: @DominikKutek So am I right in saying that if random vectors $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then their covariance matrix is simply a matrix with a zero in every element?

Comment: @Daya: yes, they are uncorrelated if and only if their cross-covariance matrix $C_{ij}$ is zero: $C_{ij}=E[x_i,y_j]-E[x_i]E[y_j]=0$. Independence implies "uncorrelated".